# Set content-type of response

Tags: file, servlets, download, zip, content-type

Is it possible to change the content type of response after writing it.

I am having a requirement to write the response to .txt file. If there are any errors it should only return zip file instead of .txt in order to intimate end user about failures.

But even if i set the content type to zip file in case of exception, it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You can build the zip (not having written any headers or anything to response) and then in the end, if it succeeds, write the content-type as zip and print it to response, and if not, write txt to the content-type and print your error message.

Pseudo-code:

```
Zip zip = null;
try
{
  zip = buildZip();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   response.setContentType("text/html");
   response.getOutputStream().print("Error");
   return;
}
response.setContentType("application/zip");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=zipfile.zip");
zip.print(response.getOutputStream());
```